# How to apply learning curves on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, r, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have started using the Azure Studio ML and would like to know if there is a way of inputting a learning curve code (python or R) into my model.

I am training with Two-Class Boosted Decision Tree and I want to check if my results are overfitting or not.

I have also found some codes for Learning Curves and I know there is a box to execute the codes in either R or Python but I do not know what I have change in the code (if I actually have to) and how do I connect my dataset to this code

Code source: http://www.ritchieng.com/machinelearning-learning-curve/

Thank you,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the document you linked, there are some Python packages used in the code source, which include `sklearn`, `matplotlib` & `numpy` that be supported on Azure ML studio. So you just need to refer to the offical tutorial [`Execute Python machine learning scripts in Azure Machine Learning Studio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts) to write your script.

For how to connect your dataset or load data, you can refer to these documents if using Python to do it.

1. [Access datasets with Python using the Azure Machine Learning Python client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-python-data-access)
2. [Move data to and from Azure Blob Storage using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-move-data-to-azure-blob-using-python)
3. [Create features for data in SQL Server using SQL and Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-create-features-sql-server)

For other ways to connect dataset or load data, please move to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/) to filter the topic via the key words `Acquire and understand data`.